# Comparing two Objects by id and creating the new one

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

So I have two objects with this structure:

```
const obj1 = { data:
   [ { 
       id: 1,
       name: 'Linda'
     },
     { 
       id: 2,
       name: 'Mark'
     }
   ];

const obj2 =  [
   { 
       id: 1,
       salary: "2000, 60 USD"
   },
undefined
 ],
 [ 
   { 
       id: 2,
       salary: "4000, 50 USD"
   },
 undefined
]
```

I need to make a function to combine both of these into one object, based on `id`.

So the final results would be:

```
const finalObj = { data:
       [ { 
           id: 1,
           name: 'Linda',
           salary: "2000, 60 USD"
         },
         { 
           id: 2,
           name: 'Mark',
           salary: "4000, 50 USD"
         }
       ];
```

I have checked other questions, but could not find anything that would help. It can be done with lodash afaik, but don't know how.

I have tried the following:

```
finalObj = obj1.data.map(x => {
                    return {
                        ...x,
                        ...obj2
                    }
```

But it didn't map correctly.

Thanks.

EDIT: Updated `obj2` response.

Comment: have both arrays the same length? is the same `id` at the same index?

Comment: That is correct,

Comment: please add valid data strutures.

Comment: @NinaScholz, removed commas in `obj2`. Does that help?

Comment: Are you sure your `obj2` is valid?

Comment: @HassanImam, that's how it looks. Believe it or not...

Comment: Should it be converted to array first?

Comment: Yes. It should be an array.

Comment: How can I convert it to Array with valid results first...?

Comment: Where are you getting this data?

Comment: @HassanImam, from my server. I have managed to convert it to Array via `let res = _.values(obj2)`. What do i do now.

Comment: Also, updated the question.

Comment: an item of an array can not have a key, unless it is an object, but the data does not show this.

Comment: Then, how can I format it correctly...?

Answer (score 0):

You can `array#concat` both your array and then using `array#reduce` and an object lookup with id, merge your objects. Then return all the values from this object.

```js
const obj1 = { data: [{ id: 1, name: 'Linda' }, { id: 2, name: 'Mark' }]},
      obj2 = { data: [{ id: 1, salary: "2000, 60 USD"}, { id: 2, salary: "4000, 50 USD"}]},
      result = Object.values(obj1.data.concat(obj2.data).reduce((r,o) => {
        r[o.id] = r[o.id] || {};
        r[o.id] = {...r[o.id], ...o};
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. Check updated question please. That is the actual response in `obj2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for collecting all properties of the same `id` in an object. Later get the values of the map.

```js
const join = o => o && map.set(o.id, Object.assign(map.get(o.id) || {}, o));
var obj1 = { data: [{ id: 1, name: 'Linda' }, { id: 2, name: 'Mark' } ]},
    obj2 =  [{ id: 1, salary: "2000, 60 USD" }, undefined, { id: 2, salary: "4000, 50 USD" }, undefined],
    map = new Map,
    result;

obj1.data.forEach(join);
obj2.forEach(join);
result = { data: Array.from(map.values()) };
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Check updated question please. That is the actual response in `obj2`.

Comment: If I don't have `data:` in `obj2`, can I use `obj2.forEach(join);` simply?

Comment: Strange, only maps the last `id`.

Comment: what maps only the last `id`?

Comment: `console.log(result);` shows that only the last id is mapped.

Comment: i see in both object a `salary` property.

Comment: do you want to continue in chat, please? you really helped :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177620/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-johnsam).

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
const res = {
    ...obj1, // take the initial object
    data: obj1.data.map(item => ({ // rewrite data property by iterate each item 
                                   // and merge item with corresponding 
                                   // object from obj2
        ...item, // take the item object
        ...obj2.find(({ id }) => id === item.id) // find corresponding object 
    }))
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: @JohnSam I am added comments

Comment: Close. @stasovlas, do you want to join chat so we can continue.. I am making an error somewhere please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which would combine the objects and not overwrite the properties but only add the ones that are missing as well as avoid the `undefined` etc:

```js
const names = {data: [{ id: 1, name: 'Linda' },{ id: 2, name: 'Mark' }]}
const salaries = [{ id: 1, salary: "2000, 60 USD" }, undefined]

var result = _.mapValues(names.data, x => {
  let hit = _.find(salaries, y => y ? y.id === x.id : null)
  return hit ? _.defaults(x, hit) : x
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

We are using `mapValues` to get to the values of `names.data` and look through them and for each of them get a hit in the `salaries`. If the hit exists we `default` the props of the hit with the current data object and return. Hope this helps.